# ExtJs Calendar item doesn't show in month view

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to see ExtJs calendar item in month view but it doesn't show. It's only happening in January month (2017). I can see the record in week view.
I uploaded an image. Please take a look.
How can I fix that problem ?
Thank you.

[image: image link is here.]

Comment: Well, it works for me: https://i.imgur.com/gxJCXqf.png

Comment: How did you do that ? I can' t understand how it's working :) Are you using ExtJs 6.0 version ?

Comment: By the way that issue only happening in Google Chrome browser. When I used to firefox or internet explorer, it works properly.

Comment: Using Chrome 55, I opened the URL from your screenshot. I clicked "Week", clicked ">", clicked ">", scrolled to the top using mousewheel, clicked into the Jan8/12am cell, typed "Test", clicked "Save", clicked "Month" and found everything I needed for the screenshot. Reproducible on two computers (one Windows 10 and one Windows 8.1, both Chrome 55)